# Download file: direct access to application google chrome or another way to do it

Tags: javascript, html, file, download

hello friend i am making an aplication based on web plataform html5 css3 ... 
and i have a web site with this, but i thought creat a direct link to shout(pop) this aplication to end user from the desktop.

example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.me/sources/directaccess/IcarosNetWeb.Ink" download="IcarosNetWeb">Descarga Aplicativo</a>
```

[image]

but it not work on chrome or other browser. i get error file or uncomplete download. file named: IcarosNetWeb.downkload ....

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved by this way**

Direct Access

As not able to find the way to do it directly. I created a free mechanism:
1. Create a .bat file (Batch command line) Hiden.(This is the task: create the shortcut to the application with its parameters.)

2. Compressing the .bat file within a file self-extracting WinRAR and run the .bat file at the end of the extraction, automatically.
3. Create Hidden Log File on C:/ if have problem executing.

**AutoInstall.bat file**

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET LinkName=MyAplication
SET Esc_LinkDest=%%HOMEDRIVE%%%%HOMEPATH%%\Desktop\!LinkName!.lnk
SET Esc_LinkTarget=%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
SET Esc_WorkDir=%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\Google\Chrome\Application
SET Esc_Icon=%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe,6
SET Esc_URL=www.google.com
SET Esc_ARG=--app=http://!Esc_URL!/
SET cSctVBS=CreateShortcut.vbs
SET LOG=".\%~N0_runtime.log"
((
  echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^) 
  echo sLinkFile = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_LinkDest!"^)
  echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut^(sLinkFile^) 
  echo oLink.TargetPath = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_LinkTarget!"^)
  echo oLink.WindowStyle = 1
  echo oLink.IconLocation = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_Icon!"^)
  echo oLink.Arguments = !Esc_URL!
  echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_WorkDir!"^)
  echo oLink.Description = "Internet Access"
  echo oLink.Save
)1>!cSctVBS!
cscript //nologo .\!cSctVBS!
DEL !cSctVBS! /f /q
)1>> !LOG! 2>>&1
attrib +h !LOG!
```

**in Winrar:**

put SFX File option, go Advance Tab and Click SFX FIle, on tab General add folder Extraction C:/ and on Instaltion tab in Instaltion after Extraction field add the full name (no path) .bat aplication.